# Multiple url levels in .NET Web API

Tags: .net, routes, asp.net-web-api

I'm setting up a rest service using the new .NET Web API, and I've come across a little issue. We want to have a little different routing, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

```
public class FormController : ApiController
{

    // api/form
    public string Get()
    {
        return "OK-Get";
    }
    // api/form/method1
    public string Method1()
    {
        return "OK1";
    }
    // api/form/method2
    public string Method2()
    {
        return "OK2";
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. If I go to `/api/form/method2`, I get `OK-Get` as a response.

I'm thinking this has to do with routing, but I'm not sure, since I haven't used MVC before. I've tried setting it up like this in the `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "FormApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/form/{action}"
);
```

But that did nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The routing is almost correct but the main problem is that you are missing the required HttpMethod Attributes on the other action methods. `[HttpGet]` is inferred on the first method because of its name. This is what you need:

```
public class FormController : ApiController
{
    // api/form
    public string Get()
    {
        return "OK-Get";
    }

    // api/form/method1
    [HttpGet]
    public string Method1()
    {
        return "OK1";
    }

    // api/form/method2
    [HttpGet]
    public string Method2()
    {
        return "OK2";
    }
}
```

With a route map that belongs in App_Start/RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "FormApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/form/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "form", action = "Get"}
);
```

For more information read http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection

Comment: That worked! Thank you. Just one note, the route config needs to be in the `WebApiConfig.cs` for it to take effect.